# How does Go's net library determine req.RemoteAddr field?

Tags: go

Researching on how a server can figure out a client's IP address, I see that one needs to inspect the X-Forwarded-For header chain.

I understand that the client, ISP, and then routers and proxies declare their IP addresses there.

However, the server handler also has access to `req.RemoteAddr` field to read the client's IP address. How is that RemoteAddr determined exactly? Is it based on a specific header in the request? If yes, which one(s)?

I have tried inspecting the usage of the field and how it is set but the implementation details are hidden behind an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The net/http server sets [RemoteAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.RemoteAddr) to the [string](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Addr.String) form of the [network connection's remote address](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn.RemoteAddr). The string is typically in the format "IP:port".

In the case of a TCP connection (the typical scenario), the network connection remote address is taken from the [IP source address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Source_address) and the [TCP source port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure).

The address can be the address of the client or a proxy.

The net/http server does not consider the headers when setting RemoteAddr.

Comment: Where does it infer the network connection's IP:port from?

Comment: I realize I might have phrased my question inaccurately. What I am wondering, is what is the ultimate source of truth for the value stored in `RemoteAddr`? Is it a header? is it a portion of a packet sent as part of a request? Is it something else?